# How to get a list of dependencies from package.json file in table format

Tags: node.js, dependencies, extract, package.json

I would like to compile extract all dependencies from package.json and put them into a table (or any other human readable format).

Is there a tool that I can use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: It's been a few years and the next time I had to do this I decided to write a simple, web based formatter. You can find it on [this GitHub pages link](https://s-maciejewski.github.io/pretty-package/). It can handle csv and Markdown and can get licenses from npm registry.

Old answer:

Not sure about how to visualize it nicely as a table, but if you consider a graph to be human readable, then [NPMGraph](https://npmgraph.js.org/) is a great tool to take a quick look at your dependencies based on your `package.json`.

You can also export the graph as .svg if you need it for some kind of documentation.

The closest thing to a table that I know of would simply be the output of `npm list` - it's a tree, but it quite easily readable and could easily be converted to a table if needed. If the output is too much for you, I would advise using i.e. `npm list --depth=0`

Comment: Thank you for your response Sebastian. I would have hoped there is some tool by now which can simply output all those by simply parsing the package.json file (something i can use online). As I do not want to rely on CLI, but if that is the best thing available i will have to resort to that

Comment: If you found it helpful, I would appreciate accepting the answer